# Use Result of Excel Formula Evaluated in If Statement Without Recalculating

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have encountered this situation many, many, times and have not found any kind of answer (including here on SO).

I would have an "IF" statement in Excel, where the condition being evaluated includes a very long formula.  To improve re-calculation speed, I'd like to be able to test the result and, if it meets the criteria, use the already calculated result instead of having Excel calculate it again.  In other words, use the 1st approach & not the 2nd as shown below:

```
1)  =if([long formula] = criteria, [use result of long formula], [calc something else])
```

versus

```
1)  =if([long formula] = criteria, [calc long formula again], [calc something else])
```

Also, I'd prefer not to have to put the formula in another cell for a variety of reasons, but mainly so I wouldn't have to hide it from other users, etc.

Does anyone know of there is some method for doing this?

Comment: Some of what you are asking is possible but the non-conforming condition (*False*) would have to be an error. See the online help page for the new(er) [IFERROR function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5) and even newer [IFNA function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461).

Answer (score 1):

Type the long formula into another cell and then name that cell. ([Define and use names](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64?CorrelationId=ae9e88ae-cc3f-470e-b706-014b74a14be0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US))

Then reference the name of that cell in place of the long formula. In the example below I put the formula in A1 and named it 'Fred', then in A2 I am using the formula `=IF(Fred>8,Yes,Fred)` and it returns the formula:

[image: Screen]

If you do not want to enter it in another cell, go to the Formula tab and click "Define Name" and you can enter a Name for reference and the formula below as a constant:

[image]

It looks like this tries to assign relative cell references however so I would be sure to use absolute location references within the formula (predicated by $).

Comment: Perfect!  I hadn't even thought about defining a named range with a formula (and the relative references is actually something I wanted anyway).

Comment: You should be aware that if you put the expensive formula inside a defined name then the expensive formula will be calculated every single time the defined name is referenced. This does not happen if the expensive formula is in a cell and the defined name refers to the cell.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - So if an IF statement is of the form "=IF(Fred>8,Yes,Fred)", "Fred" is calculated twice?  That does kind of defeat the purpose of what I was trying to do -- that is, avoid calculating the long formula more than once.

Comment: The IF statement does short-circuit: so if Fred is >8 then Fred only gets referenced and calculated once, but if Fred<=8 then Fred gets referenced and calculated twice. But if Fred just refers to a cell containing the expensive formula the expensive formula only gets calculated once even when Fred gets evaluated twice.